# SQL View with Joins, Grouping, and Counts of a value in a field

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

The goal is to wind up with a view that shows the 50 most common procedure codes for the combination of each type and specialty. (Specialty codes can repeat in different types)

I have two tables:

table `providers` contains:
provider_type
provider_specialty
provider_id
(and some data that doesn't matter for this problem)

Table `services` contains:
provider_id
procedure_code
(and some other data points - not relevant)

The end result would look something like:

```
Provider Type  |  Provider Specialty |  Procedure Code  |  Count
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-------
00             |  01                 | 97012            |  500 
00             |  01                 | 97013            |  450
00             |  02                 | 97012            |  270
00             |  02                 | 97013            |  900
01             |  01                 | 97012            |  845
01             |  01                 | 97013            |  1200
```

Any Ideas? I know this is a super complex query, I've considered just building a script to do the updates periodicity, but I'd rather have more real-time data.

Comment: so where's procedure codes in your tables?

Comment: Sorry - service codes and procedure codes are the same thing. Edited.They don't have different names in the table - just used interchangeably in the office.

Comment: For each individual type and specialty or for each *combination* of type and specialty?

Comment: Combination of Type and Specialty. Sorry! Updating!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the 50 most common procedure codes for the combination of each type
>   and specialty

Should work like this:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT p.provider_type, p.provider_specialty, s.procedure_code
          ,count(*) AS ct
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY p.provider_type, p.provider_specialty
                              ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS r
    FROM   providers p
    JOIN   services s USING (provider_id)
    GROUP  BY 1,2,3
    )
SELECT x.provider_type, x.provider_specialty, x.procedure_code, x.ct
FROM   x
WHERE  x.r <= 50
ORDER  BY 1,2,4,3;
```

#### Major points

- I use a CTE (PostgreSQL 8.4 or later), you could do the same with a subquery.
- I use the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) (again, PostgreSQL 8.4 or later), to qualify the 50 most common values in `procedure_code`.
- Note that you can `ORDER BY count(*)` inside the `OVER` clause. That is, use the result from an aggregate function in a window function, because **window functions are applied after aggregate functions**.
- You could *not* do the same with `ORDER BY ct`, because the alias is not known to the window function.
- The final `SELECT` is easy then, just return the top 50 for each group.

Comment: This is showing ones with Less than 50 Instances. I want to show the 50 with the most instances. Sorry if that was unclear. I'm still going to save this for another view though so thanks.

Comment: I fixed the statement, I think.

Comment: @JensSchauder: Thanx, that should do it.